# Proving two equations are equal with Demorgans

Tags: computer-science, boolean-logic, demorgans-law

I'm trying to prove that these two equations are equal using Demorgans / other basic laws. It's been a while since i've done Boolean logic and am having trouble. Can anyone help me out with it?

```
E = ((A·B) + (A·C) + (B·C)) ·-(A·B·C)
E = (A·B·-C) + (A·-B·C) + (-A·B·C)
```

After using Demorgans on the first one, I get..

```
E = ((A·B) + (A·C) + (B·C)) · -A + -B + -C
```

I'm not too sure where to go after this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly which "basic rules" you're allowed to use, but the easiest way is to factor the expression. More formally, you would repeatedly apply the rule `(A + B)C <=> AC + BC`. If we do this to your derived expression, we get:

```
E = AB(-A) + AC(-A) + BC(-A) + AB(-B) + AC(-B) + BC(-B) + AB(-C) + AC(-C) + BC(-C)
```

At this point we can take advantage of the rules `A(-A) <=> 0` and `0A <=> 0` (Where `0` represents a false value). Applying these two rules (and dropping `0` values), and rearranging variables slightly, gives us the desired result:

```
E = (-A)BC + A(-B)C + AB(-C)
```